# addEventListener isn't triggering on keypress

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm trying to add custom keys to trigger events. I can get the `keyup` and the `keydown` events to work but for some reason the `keypress` event isn't working. I have seen many duplicates to these but most is in jquery.

In addition, in researching this, I came across the documentation that states that `keyCode` is deprecated and `key` should be used instead. However if I write

```
if (event.key === 74)
```

the code doesn't work

The code below is a simple example of what i'm trying to do.

```js
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 74) {
    console.log('Show me');
  }
});
```

Comment: Use `keydown` instead

Comment: I need `keypress`  because `keydown` will require me to hold it down.

Comment: `keydown` doesn't require you to hold the key down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine (assuming you are entering a **capital** `J`).

If you also want to check against a lowercase `J`, the keyCode would be `106`:

```js
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 74 || event.keyCode === 106) {
    console.log('Show me');
  }
});
```

Comment: I was actually looking for the common j thanks you. I didn't even realise it was testing for the capital J.

Comment: can you give me a link to the list of all keyCodes because when I research this I see common j as being 74 and no capital keycodes. example https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the capital and small j. You are using code for capital j only

```js
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
console.log(event.keyCode)
  if (event.keyCode === 74 || event.keyCode === 106) {
    console.log('Show me');
  }
});
```

Comment: I realised this after seeing Obsidian Age's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the even.which when you check for J(74):

```js
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.which === 74) {
    console.log('Show me');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use key down instead, this will catch both upper and lower case `j`.

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 74) {
    console.log('Show me');
  }
});
```